# Get the deepest coverage site from a list of continuous span

Tags: python, algorithm, range

> What dose **continuous span** look like?

Continuous span is represented by a tuple, `(start, end)`.

eg, `(2, 8)` refers to a region starts from 2 and end with 8.

> What does **deepest coverage** mean?

For a list of spans, eg `[(0, 4), (2, 8), (5, 10), (6, 9)]`, the pileup result will be:

```
│ 0......4
│    2...........8
│          5.........10
│            6.....9
└────────────────────────
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

The deepest coverage of span is `(6, 8)`, which is 3.

In this case, the expected return should be `(6,8)`

> My solution

I don't known how to represent continuous span, thus, I break each continuous span in to list of numbers, and try to found the most common one from the counter result.

```py
from collections import Couter
import numpy as np

density = Counter()
for start, end in SPAN_LIST:
    density.update(
        np.round(np.arange(start, end, 0.01)), 2)
    )
most_dense_site, most_dense_count = density.most_common()[0]
```

The result might not be accurate, and the speed is extremely slow for a large list (about billions of items).
I know that if I increase the precision, the result will be more accurate, but it will also waste more memory.

**I would like to know how to speed up the process and make the result more accurate in a better way?**

Comment: So what is **YOUR** question / problem?

Comment: `(max([i[0] for i in SPAN_LIST]), min([i[1]for i in SPAN_LIST]))` or am i missing something?

Comment: @NihalSangeeth The spans are not expected to be overlapping to one region. eg, [(2, 8), (5, 10), (16, 19)]

Comment: @MrSmith42 I had highlighted the question. It is clear now?

Comment: I've found the answer to the same question on Software Engineering Stack Exchange: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/330889 . A more verbose article can be found here: http://www.zrzahid.com/maximum-number-of-overlapping-intervals/

Comment: Thank your very much @miloszlakomy. it looks relevant, but there is no concrete solution there. I might follow the description and write one here.

Comment: @miloszlakomy Thanks for the article. Seem that it is describing algorithm for calculating the max count, instead of querying the max overlapping interval.

Answer (score 1):

Elaborating on the comment section:

The solution is to go through all starts and ends of ranges, mixed together, in order, "sweeping" through these points. We will consider them events and we will keep track of how many ranges we currently visit. An event triggered by a start of a range will increase the count of currently visited ranges. An event triggered by an end of a range will decrease the count of currently visited ranges.

(The code below assumes the ranges are half-open, including starts but not ends.)

Playground: https://ideone.com/fOAOXr

```py
def deepest_coverage(span_list):
    if not span_list:
        raise ValueError("The given list must be non-empty")

    events = []
    for start, end in span_list:
        events.append((start, 1))
        events.append((end, -1))

    events.sort()

    ret = None
    most_visited = currently_visited = 0
    for i in range(len(events)):
        currently_visited += events[i][1]
        if currently_visited > most_visited:
            most_visited = currently_visited
            ret = events[i][0], events[i+1][0]

    return ret


print(deepest_coverage([(0, 4), (2, 8), (5, 10), (6, 9)]))
```

Output:

```py
(6, 8)
```

---

Resources:

- [Wikipedia: Sweep line algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_line_algorithm)
- [Software Engineering Stack Exchange: Job scheduling: algorithm to find the maximum number of overlapping jobs?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/330889)
- [Maximum number of overlapping intervals – Merge Overlapping Intervals – Max Task Load](http://www.zrzahid.com/maximum-number-of-overlapping-intervals/)

Answer (score 0):

I write this solution with sweep line algorithm in Python.

1. Spans List and flatten into Positions List, and the startpoint and endpoint identity and recorded by score.
2. Adjacent startpoint and endpoints are merged, for improving performance and fixing a wrong position bug.
3. Looping the position list and record the deepest span with its score.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

def get_deepest_coverage(span_list):
    """Get the span with the deepest coverage."""
    pos_dict = defaultdict(int)
    for start, end in span_list:
        pos_dict[start] += 1
        pos_dict[end] -= 1
    pos_list = sorted((k, v) for k, v in pos_dict.items() if v)

    deepest_start = deepest_end = None
    deepest_count = current_count = 0
    for index, (pos, score) in enumerate(pos_list):
        current_count += score
        if current_count > deepest_count:
            deepest_count = current_count
            deepest_start, deepest_end = pos, pos_list[index + 1][0]

    return deepest_start, deepest_end, deepest_count


print(get_deepest_coverage([(2, 8), (5, 7), (7, 20)]))
```

**Thanks @miloszlakomy for all the materials. And the nice solution.**

(I take me a whole afternoon to write this snippet, and found @miloszlakomy has posted the answer here.)

---

*And thanks xxx for keeping voting down **all** my post, without which I won't have motivation to finish this problem by myself.*